# ASP.Net C# - Postback and Session objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, postback, session-variables

I want to check for Session objects and if none exist, redirect the user to index.html.

Regarding the two pieces of code below, I was wondering when should I use one over the other?

I think I should use version 1 all the time but I'm unsure.

version 1:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Session.Count == 0)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/index.html");
        }
        else
        {
            //code
        }
    }
}
```

version 2:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session.Count == 0)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/index.html");
    }
    else if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        //code
    }
}
```

EDIT: Thank you for the replies.  I think the two conditions shouldn't be linked and two *if* statements would be most appropriate (in my situation).

Comment: you should move your question to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, anyway asking for a postback is a overkill since you want to perform a redirect I'd stick to solution number 2

Comment: They do different things, they are not different versions of the same functionality. If it is a postback (in your first example), the `if` statement which evaluates the session will never be hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it depends. There is a minor difference in logic there.

Version 1 will redirect only if it's not a `Postback` action, i.e. when a user is not submitting a form.

Version 2 will redirect if a user submits a form or requests a page.

I would go for option 3:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session.Count == 0)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/index.html");
        return; //return here so this logic isn't mixed with the postback logic.
    }

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        //code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Essentially your session check and postback check are parts of two different workflows, so to say. So chaining them in one `if-else` block might only confuse future code reader. I would suggest third version:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session.Count == 0)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/index.html");
        return;
    }

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        //code
    }
}
```

Here two checks are separated, and code flow appears to be more transparent.

Comment: I don't believe this question can be answered until OP confirms the order in which he wants to do the evaluating. This isn't really a question worthy of SO as he's asking what he should code (in terms of how it should function).

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on what you are trying to achieve.  Version 1 will never redirect on a postback, even if Session.Count == 0.  Without knowing what you want to accomplish it is impossible to tell you which one to use.

Comment: This is the only answer short of sending OP to stackexchange's code-review.